# Combining multiple regex patterns 1 for matching and rest for excluding

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a python function that can split a text into sentences. I want to split on period(.), question mark (?) or an exclamation (!). There are however, some exclusions for this criteria which I have identified as regular expressions. pattern1 through 5 are for exclusions and pattern6 is for matching. I want to find all patterns which match pattern6 but must not match any of the patterns 1 to 5. Is it possible to do so in Python regex? Or am I not thinking in the right direction.

```
pattern1 = '\. [a-z]'  
pattern2 = '\.\d' 
pattern2 = '(Mr|Mrs|Dr|Jr)\. [A-Z]' 
pattern4 = '[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]' 
pattern5 = '\.(\.|,)'

pattern6 = '\.[\s][A-Z]'
```

When I combined pattern 1 to 5 with | in pythex,

```
pattern1|pattern2|patter3|pattern4|pattern5
```

I could find all the scenarios that I wanted to exclude. Then I tried excluding them with ^ and combining with pattern6 to get a very ugly regex:

```
(^((\. [a-z])|(\.\d)|((Mr|Dr|Jr|Mrs)\.[A-Z])|([A-Za-z]\.[A-Za-z])|(\.(\.|,))))|(\.[\s][A-Z])
```

here is the pattern replaced with pattern names for simplicity

```
(^((pattern1)|(pattern2)|(pattern3)|(pattern4)|(pattern5)))|(pattern6)
```

This is working to some extent but failing for the cases with "Mr. Smith" etc. I have just started learning regex so please forgive me for my dirty code. Would appreciate if you could provide guideline for writing good readable regular expressions.

Adding sample input:

> Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a
>   lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case,
>   this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.

Correct output should be a list of sentences

An incorrect output is any split at . not marking the end of a sentence

Comment: sample input, sample failure output, sample correct output?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider splitting on pattern 6 only, then excluding patterns 3 and 5 using lookarounds, since those are the only ones that could still match despite enforcing pattern 6 (pattern 3 having space+uppercase after period and pattern 5 for having to ignore periods in a row).

This is pattern 6 with a positive lookahead:

```
\.(?=\s[A-Z])
```

To exclude pattern 3, add negative lookbehinds:

```
(?<!Mr|Dr|Jr)(?<!Mrs)\.(?=\s[A-Z])
```

I used a separate negative lookbehind because python's lookbehinds cannot be of variable width. All of `Mr`, `Dr` and `Jr` are 2 characters long, but `Mrs` 3.

You can shorter that last regex to:

```
(?<![MDJ]r)(?<!Mrs)\.(?=\s[A-Z])
```

To exclude patter 5 now, another negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![MDJ]r)(?<!Mrs)(?<!\.)\.(?=\s[A-Z])
```

After this, it won't split on consecutive periods.

Now that you've got a period down, you can easily use a character class to split on `!` and `?`:

```
(?<![MDJ]r)(?<!Mrs)(?<!\.)[.?!](?=\s[A-Z])
```

---

By the way, `^` is not exactly used for negation in regex. `[^ ... ]` instead is used for negation when you don't care about the order of characters. For instance, `[^aeiou]` will match any one character except the letters `aeiou` in any order. Also, most meta characters in regex lose their meaning within character classes (this is what something enclosed in square brackets is). For example, `()` become literal characters between `[]` and no more can be used for grouping.

`^` is used outside character classes to mean the beginning of a line.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Feeling stupid that I used ^ for negation although I read that before... seems like I need to get some sleep. Yet to read about lookahead and lookbehind. The concept is new to me.

Comment: @user3097807 Don't worry about it, when you start to learn regex, there are so many symbols that you have to look out for and I know it's not easy to tell them apart. Take you time. And I would suggest getting the basics first. Lookaheads and lookbehinds are somewhat more advanced syntax. Try to understand character classes, capture and non-capture groups, anchor, basic quantifiers and backreferences first. Then move to lookarounds (lookahead and lookbehind). I find [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) great for learning regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerry :-) I wish I could vote up your answer but I do not have that much reputation...

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge there is not exclude pattern `^` is for excluding a character from a character set as in [^ab] outside it means the begining of the string which is not what you want

you have to do a two step match

```
pattern1 = r'\. [a-z]'  
pattern2 = r'\.\d' 
pattern2 = r'(Mr|Mrs|Dr|Jr)\. [A-Z]' 
pattern4 = r'[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]' 
pattern5 = r'\.(\.|,)'

pattern6 = r'\.[\s][A-Z]'

if re.match(pattern6):
    if not re.match("("+pattern1+"|"+pattern2+"|"+pattern3+"|"+pattern4+"|"+pattern5+")"):
          do_whatever_you_want()
```